# Perform one action for multiple sheets

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote the following code with lets me put a text into the first shape of my first sheet

```
   Sub OpenFiles()

   With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange

   .Text = "test"

  End With


   End Sub
```

I however want to apply this to all the first shapes of the sheets in my presentation. Does anybody know how I have to enhance my code for this.

Dear regards,

Marc

Comment: So, again... -you should see [this information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on how accepting answer works. And try to stick to it where applicable. Does it cost really much?

Comment: back to your question- `sheets`? you mean `slides`? if so, you need apply simple loop: `for i=1 to activepresentation.slides.count` and so on.

Comment: KazJaw, ok will definitely do it from now on! Sorry man!

Comment: Nice to hear it but you could also go back to all your questions and approve those answers which are correct and met you needs. Thanks in the name of the community.

Comment: will do sorry for the hassle, kind of new to the whole. Awesome this community though!

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub OpenFiles()

Dim oSl as Slide

For Each oSl in ActivePresentation.Slides

  oSl.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "test"

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub OpenFiles()

Dim oSl as Slide

For Each oSl in ActivePresentation.Slides

  oSl.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "test"

End With

End Sub
```

Now see KazJaw's first comment and try it out.

Comment: Hi Steve, only had to switch your last end with statement for "next". But further it works, thanks!